# Can surf the internet but can't play online games

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, drivers, ssd

I bought an SSD-drive and a new power supply, installed Win 10 x64 on it, connected to the Internet via the TP-Link WiFi adapter TL-WN723N.

The Internet works great, I can download, watch videos on the network, etc., but as soon as I connect to the games, the connection is started, the game starts and a break occurs (or some time everything works fine with a VERY big ping and then the connection is still broken ).

When I connect the adapter to the USB port on the front of the system unit, everything works fine! The option with the mother's USB problem disappears, because remained the old version of Windows on another HDD drive, on which everything works well. The problem is not in the router, because absolutely the same problem occurs if I connect via WiFi to my phone, which distributes the Internet. Disconnected the firewall.

I tried different versions of drivers for the adapter, nothing has changed. Updated all the drivers motherboard (good there is a good utility from MSI, which automatically updates everything that you have not updated). I asked the motherboard to the latest version. I checked all devices in the device manager for new drivers in the Windows update center (some of them were updated, but the problem remained).

What could be the problem? Not the correct BIOS settings for SSD? Update the driver, but from what? Network settings? Any ideas, please.

Log of diagnostic utility FRST:

https://cloud.mail.ru/public/9rX8/71DRXFQWy - Addition.txt

https://cloud.mail.ru/public/JVbK/ijhB7WNem - frst.txt

*Perhaps this is important. There was a problem when the wireless connection was constantly falling off with the error "The default gateway is not available," I spent a day to solve the problem, but I decided somehow after reinstalling the power supply to the old one, and then returning the new one to its place, but the error still falls out periodically, but it is solved by usual network diagnostics or by removing the driver and installing it again.

Comment: Did the wireless adapter come with a short USB extension lead (or maybe you have one already) which you can try it with? It *could* be that there is electromagnetic interference round the back of the computer, e.g. from USB3.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, there is no extension lead. By the way, I also tend to electromagnetic interference, but how to test it? Why does it work well if I boot from the old HDD?

Comment: Does the old HDD happen to boot Windows 7, which doesn't have native USB3 drivers? Does the computer actually have USB3 ports? The easy way to test would be to use a short USB extension lead.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, I connected the wifi adapter to USB 3.0 and USB 2.0, I did not notice any difference. I ordered a lanyard for USB, I'll check it out tonight. Maybe everything will work, then I continue to work and continue as before or it is worth investigating the reason for the "high" electromagnetic interference round the back of the computer? Or is it considered normal?

Comment: It's a known potential problem: [PCMag article](http://uk.pcmag.com/networking-reviews-ratings-comparisons/13179/opinion/wireless-witch-the-truth-about-usb-30-and-wi-fi-interference), [Intel whitepaper](https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/io/universal-serial-bus/usb3-frequency-interference-paper.html).

Comment: @AndrewMorton, I just checked everything, thanks to the USB cable everything works fine, thanks! I can mark your answer as the best, it will be a plus to karma :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USB 3.0 can cause electromagnetic interference on 2.4 GHz devices, such as WiFi. It won't necessarily cause a total loss of signal, it might just be seen as a slower connection.

As you noticed when you plugged the adapter into the front of the computer instead of the back, moving the WiFi adapter away from the back of the computer can reduce the interference enough to enable it to work reliably.

To keep the adapter plugged into the back, you can use a short USB extension lead.

References and further reading:

- [Intel: USB 3.0* Radio Frequency Interference Impact on 2.4GHz Wireless Devices - White Paper](https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/io/universal-serial-bus/usb3-frequency-interference-paper.html)
- [PCMag: Wireless Witch: The Truth About USB 3.0 and Wi-Fi Interference](http://uk.pcmag.com/networking-reviews-ratings-comparisons/13179/opinion/wireless-witch-the-truth-about-usb-30-and-wi-fi-interference)